# TestFlight and App Store Territories

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight

Does anyone know if territory restrictions applied to an app in the store are enforced in TestFlight as well?

So if I have an app in the store restricted to the UK but I want someone in another country to be part of a beta trial are they going to able to install it?

I appreciate the easiest way is to just try it but I don't want to raise expectations if its not possible.

Answer (score 2):

According to one posting on the [Apple Developer forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682057)

> TestFlight does not have territory restrictions. When you send invitations or use a public link, any user from any territory is eligible to be a tester.

This would seem to suggest that territory restrictions are **not** applied when distributing via TestFlight.